# How does the dropbox client for Linux work?

Tags: linux, dropbox

How does the dropbox client for Linux work ?

Does it intercept read/write system calls using something like FUSE and then makes HTTP put/get calls to the dropbox server accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux supports file change detection through [iNotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) and so there is no need for any clever filing system hacks.

The really clever parts of any of the file synchronisation tools revolve around detecting which bits of a file have changed and only sending those parts (delta changes). Any file sync service that doesn't include this is pretty hopeless. Thankfully, Dropbox have this reasonably well nailed.